# MySQL: Select first row with value in interval

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (`id` INT, `num` INT);
INSERT INTO table1 (`id`, `num`) VALUES
     (1, 1),
     (1, 5),
     (1, 7),
     (1, 12),
     (1, 22),
     (1, 23),
     (1, 24),
     (2, 1),
     (2, 6);
```

How do I select a row for each `num` interval of 5 (ie. select the first row for [0,5), the first for [5,10), the first for [10,15), etc.), with a given `id`? Is this possible with a MySQL query, or must I process it in a programming language later?

For reference, the output I'd want for `id=1`:

```
(1, 1), (1,5), (1,12), (1,22)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short query:

```
select min(num), ceiling((num + 1)/5)
from table1
where id = 1
group by ceiling((num + 1)/5);
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Changed it slightly for cleaner output: `SELECT min(num) AS "num" FROM table1 WHERE id=1 GROUP BY CEILING((num + 1)/5);`

Comment: I'm glad that it helped.